# Altering a column within a CSV in Python

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, csv

How do i select column "id" within my CSV and add a string to it?

Column ID is a number like "5474548384".
I would like to select this column and alter it to add the following: 'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/' to create a link. Screenshot of CSV is at the bottom of this post

Any suggestions on how to alter this column in my CSV?

```
import requests
import expansions
import os
import json
import pandas as pd
import csv
import sys
import time


bearer_token = "removed for privacy "

search_url = "https://api.twitter.com/2/tweets/search/all"

query_params = {'query': '("covid") i -is:retweet -is:verified -baby -lotion -shampoo lang:en has:geo place_country:US',
                'tweet.fields':'created_at,lang,text,geo,author_id,id,public_metrics,referenced_tweets',
                'expansions':'geo.place_id,author_id', 
                'place.fields':'contained_within,country,country_code,full_name,geo,id,name,place_type',
                'user.fields':'description,username,id',
                'start_time':'2021-02-27T00:00:01.000Z',
                'end_time':'2021-02-27T23:30:00.000Z',
                'max_results':'10'}

def create_headers(bearer_token):
    headers = {"Authorization": "Bearer {}".format(bearer_token)}
    return headers


def connect_to_endpoint(url, headers, params):
    response = requests.request("GET", search_url, headers=headers, params=params)

    if response.status_code != 200:
        raise Exception(response.status_code, response.text)
    return response.json()


def main():
    headers = create_headers(bearer_token)
    json_response = connect_to_endpoint(search_url, headers, query_params)

    json_response = expansions.flatten(json_response) 
    df = pd.json_normalize(json_response['data'])
    drop = df['author.description'].str.contains('news')
    
    result = df[-drop]
    result.to_csv("mydata.csv", encoding="utf-8-sig")
    
if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

[image]

Answer (score 2):

After getting the dataframe, you can add the prefix like this:

```
prefix = 'https://twitter.com/twitter/statuses/'
df['id'] = prefix + df['id'].astype(str)
```